# sorting setup with datatable.net (server side)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sorting, datatables

I use a library to render my database in a table:
https://datatables.net/

My problem is that it only sort my first colum well. 
on the code side it is `[0]` and my first column is `"id"`.

Each time I try to setup it I receive this message error from the network inspection of Chrome

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 2 in <b>/.../xxx/.../appel.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'asc LIMIT 0, 10' at line 1 in .../xxx/.../appel.php:37
Stack trace:
#0 .../xxx/.../appel.php(37): PDOStatement-&gt;execute()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>.../xxx/.../appel.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
```

I'm loosing my hairs I have absolutely no idea of what happens...
On the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) I see that

```
order[i][column]    integer Column to which ordering should be applied. This is an index reference to the columns array of information that is also submitted to the server.
order[i][dir]   string  Ordering direction for this column. It will be asc or desc to indicate ascending ordering or descending ordering, respectively.
```

So that should work........

Here is my AJAX call

```
var dataTable = $('#tableau').DataTable({
        "processing":true,
        "serverSide":true,
        "order":[],
        "ajax":{
            url:"actions/appel.php", // adresse du script AJAX
            type:"POST"
        },

        "columnDefs":[
            {
                "targets":[3, 4, 5], // exeptions des ordres de triage
                "orderable":false,
            },
        ],
    });
```

and my PHP code (appel.php)

```
if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order'][2]['column'].' '.$_POST['order'][0]['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}
```

Does someone have an idea of what could go wrong ?!?

Answer (score 0):

As you noted in your question `$_POST['order'][2]['column']` is integer which makes ordering clause invalid (for example, `ORDER BY 2 asc`).

I recommend using `ssp.class.php` for server-side processing using PHP. It is available in official DataTables distribution.